# How do I get requests from multiple websites in my code?

Tags: python

The code is:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')

print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))
count = 0
while True:
    lowestprice = 1234567890
    for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&pageNumber=48').json():
        try:
            price = locale.atof(limited['BestPrice'])
            if price < lowestprice:
                limitedname = limited['Name']
                limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
                lowestprice = price

        except ValueError as ve:
            print(" ")

    print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
    sleep(1)

    if lowestprice <= 220 and count == 0:
        webbrowser.open(limitedurl, new=2)
        count += 1
```

As you can see I am getting requests from one link. The URL ends with `pageNumber=48`. I am trying to get the requests from the pages 1-48.

for example:
requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&pageNumber=1').json():
requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&pageNumber=2').json():
requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&pageNumber=3').json():

etc, all the way up to 48.

How do I get the requests from these 48 pages, and what do I do with the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Insteead of `while True` use a for loop `for i in range(48)` or use a variable, and then use string interpolation `request.get(f"your_url..PageNumber={i}")`
What I also see you are trying to do I would say it is going to be a better idea to first to go through all the pages and collect all the data and then just find the best price.

Comment: This worked really well. However, the code goes through the links one-by-one 48 times. Is there anyway I can make it instantly go through all the links, instead of going through one-by-one? Also, I added a while loop so that the process never stops, as I am trying to constantly scrape the lowest price fast.

Comment: if the api provider does not provide a way to get multiple pages at a time you cannot do it from python, you still have to create a request for every single page. Read the documentation maybe they provide a way to get `pages=all` or `nrecords=`.